# React native live hot reload not working on Windows

Tags: react-native

Windows 7 64bits
Genymotion

I just upgraded my code to react native `0.30, 0.31, 0.32`. Live and hot reload not working anymore. It works perfect in `0.28`.

I tried on clean project also not working and no error in cmd and js debugger.

Here is the progress

```
react-native init Project
cd Project
react-native run-android
then in Genymotion
Enable Live Reload
Enable Hot Loader
```

The app is refreshed when file saved but nothing changed.

The only way to make the app reload is `react-native run-android` again.

Any idea?

Comment: is windows+R working or ctrl+R?

Comment: is there any problem with the watch? maybe, raise an issue on react-native in github.

Comment: @BurakKarasoy  no,  double R or menu > reload not work

Comment: Unfortunately, React-Native does not support Windows officially. Windows side must be handled by the community. Also It never works for me properly :)

Answer (score -1):

You read this article

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7257

Note: Version 0.32 , directory node-haste moved to node_modules\react-native\packager\react-packager\src\node-haste

Try again, please